# React-Native Uploading Own Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having a bit of a problem. I can't figure out how to implement a design like psd to my react-native code so for example i might have a design from photoshop for the profile page and how would i implement that into my code?

Thank You.

Comment: There's no fast way to do this. You'll have to look through the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and [examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples) and learn the components to design it yourself.

Comment: @JosephRoque Then how does snapchat etc upload their own designs?

Comment: Snapchat almost certainly doesn't use React Native, like most major companies. But regardless of what technologies they use, they'll all do what I've described above, use the components available to them to implement their designs. There's no PSD to code converter. You have to write the code yourself, so it resembles your design.

Comment: Hire a developer to do that for you. React Native is not a tool for converting psd file into actual code. You has to break your design into components and then glue them together

Comment: @thangngoc89 do you mean just get each piece of the design and add it and I am a developer... and im not trying to turn my psd into code ...

Comment: Yes. React is all about composition.

Comment: @thangngoc89 so if i wanted something like https://gyazo.com/54914b1f9fb49f4f0f569cb3d7ab9290 how would i get something like that and then have content where the grey  area is ?